# DataGrip shows a time substantially slower than EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Tags: postgresql, performance, datagrip, postgresql-performance

I searched alot for the answer to my question.

I have a table with 134 rows and 4 rows. My EXPLAIN ANALYZE says the execution time was: `0.038ms`. But the actual execution time (using DataGrip) was: `123ms`

A complex query with multiple joins shows these stats:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE execution time: `38.605ms`
DataGrip execution time: `177ms`

My VPS has 2GB ram and 2 vCores.

Is it more likely a problem with my server or my config, or is this behavior normal?

Here is the EXPLAIN ANALAYZE of the simple select:

```
Seq Scan on champions  (cost=0.00..4.34 rows=134 width=37) (actual time=0.007..0.024 rows=134 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.053 ms
Execution time: 0.044 ms
```

Here is the log of DataGrip:

```
[2017-02-10 21:38:30] 134 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 135ms (execution: 127ms, fetching: 8ms)
```

I am really confused!

EDIT:

These are my only changes to my config:

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 1536MB
work_mem = 32MB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Answer (score 3):

- `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is showing you the *planning* and *execution time*.
- DataGrip is showing you the *completion* time. This may include,

  1. Network transit
  2. Drawing in the GUI, etc.

Just think, if you have a one-row table with one `bytea` column that contains 2GB, transferring it across the network or even using TCP/IP will be a substantial transit compared to the planning and execution of the query.

> [2017-02-10 21:38:30] 134 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 135ms (execution: 127ms, fetching: 8ms)

That's 134 rows you didn't have to retrieve using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: The 134 rows were just a simple select like: `SELECT * FROM champions`

Comment: The most confusing thing is, that the night I wrote the complex query for example it actually ran in 35ms~ now every query needs 120ms~

I don't know what happened. Also if I try to fetch any table in C# or nodejs it also takes 120ms plus...

Comment: How are you connection pooling? Are you connecting over TCP/IP, or sockets? Does the problem persist to the same degree if you `LIMIT 0`

Comment: Ok so in DataGrip nothing changes with LIMIT 0. The connection pooling is handled by DataGrip or the ADO.NET driver in C# or the nodejs package. However if I run the query on the server in psql it really takes 0.3ms~. The connection is in TCP/IP. So fetching 0 rows and drawing 0 rows can't take 120ms can it? Is it a problem with my server or with my config most likely?

Comment: Is this being run on the same machine you're running `psql` on, and you running `psql` with TCP/IP or Unix sockets?

Comment: I ran `psql` over putty on my VPS over TCP/IP. My DataGrip is connected through TCP/IP as well. I have found after setting up a firewall on the VPS the execution time became much better. The simple select runs without caching in `94ms` and with caching in `37ms`. My complicated query runs in `75ms` without caching and in `54ms` after being cached.

So it is most likely a problem with my server, isn't it? But it is still a lot slower than the explain analyze.